# Can't cd to Desktop folder Mac commandline

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal

I am using OSX Lion and every time I tried to cd to my Desktop folder using "cd ~" and cd "Desktop" it stays in my home directory instead of going to Desktop. I've tried to perform the commands using sudo but it makes no difference.

Thanks.

Comment: If you type `pwd` and press Enter, what is the output? (Star out username if you want)

Comment: What's the output of `ls`?

Comment: Does `cd ~/Documents` work ?

Comment: After doing `pwd` I realized I was in another user's home folder. That's why I couldn't access the home folder. But I am the administrator, why can't I access the other standard user's folder, even with `sudo`? It looks like their Public folder is the only one I could access.

Comment: @David: Using `sudo` doesn't mean you _own_ the files from other users. Permissions still apply.

Comment: @Karolos: But if I am the administrator of a machine, I should be able to access other user's file when I wanted. Is there anyway to add a rule on Macs that will let all administrators have access to other people's files?

Comment: @David: No, the role of an administrator is to manage the machine and its applications. It's a breach of privacy to use administrative power to access other people's files. But in case your reasons are legitimate, you can impersonate the other user using `sudo bash` and then `su username`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the sudo command will grant access to any folder or file on the Mac.

The commands `sudo cd ~` <kbd>return</kbd> and `sudo cd Desktop` <kbd>return</kbd> only appeared to fail. In fact, both commands succeeded but exited without any output.

To demonstrate this try the command `sudo -i "cd ~;pwd"`<kbd>return</kbd> which should print `/var/root` in the terminal window.

In order to use the same commands interactively, do following:

6. `sudo -i` <kbd>return</kbd>
7. `cd ~` <kbd>return</kbd>
8. `pwd` <kbd>return</kbd>

**Output**

> `/var/root`